# While Loop to check multiple variables are equal

Tags: javascript, variables, while-loop

I'm using javascript. I'm trying set random numbers to 5 variables and they can't be equal to each other.

```
//set correct, dbcount is at 20ish now, will end up in the thousands later
correct = Math.floor(Math.random()*dbcount);

//intially set wrong variables
wrong1 = correct;
wrong2 = correct;
wrong3 = correct;
wrong4 = correct;

//set wrong ID not equal to each other or correct
while(wrong1 === correct && wrong2 === correct && wrong3 === correct && wrong4 === correct &&
      wrong1 === wrong2 && wrong1 === wrong3 && wrong1 === wrong4 &&
      wrong2 === wrong3 && wrong2 === wrong4 &&
      wrong3 === wrong4){
           wrong1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*dbcount);
           wrong2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*dbcount);
           wrong3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*dbcount);
           wrong4 = Math.floor(Math.random()*dbcount);
}
```

Every once in a while, there will be some that equal each other. Am I doing it wrong? Should I use nested if statements instead? Need something that will pretty much do something like this:

```
while(a == b == c == x == y){
    //then do stuff until a, b, c, x, y don't equal each other.
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You should probably be using arrays, not a bunch of variables.

Comment: Doesn't == suppose to follow transitive property? a == b, b == c then a == c?

Comment: Just make loop in which you generate random numbers and every time you generate random number add number from previous iteration. That way none of the numbers will be equal.

Comment: @elclanrs I do stick those values into an array later for recall with another while loop. But I'm not very advanced with coding, so I'm probably missing some short cut that could stick random numbers into an array that will check if they are the same or not.

Comment: @GoranLepur ooo that would definitely combine the array step I have after that sets those wrong variables into an array. Do you have an example of how the coding for that looks like?

Comment: @almasshaikh I'm not sure, that would definitely save me some code space! I shall try. Unfortunately it did not work. =(

Comment: @thomas Oh, i assume you want numbers to be lesser than dbcount value, adding values wouldn't work...

Comment: Anyways here's little script that generates array of random numbers.
"correct" number is first member of array.
http://plnkr.co/edit/fEh0X3K1jEKgHPcqew8D?p=preview

Comment: @SMA *late but still* - no `==` is not transitive due to [abstract equality rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using). For example with `a = ""` (empty string) `b = 0`, and `c = " "` (blank space) then `a == b` and `b == c` are both `true` however `a == c` is `false`.

Comment: @VLAZ - for String comparison, you should use equals as opposed to `==`. Also how is a = b? They are two different data types.

Comment: @SMA `==` operates on loose equality. I've linked tot he rules for performing those. As you observed,  comparing different datatypes is not preferrable, so `"" == 0` would transform the string to a number. The rules for *that* state that an empty string is transformed to a zero, hence the two are *loosely* equal. Same thing happens with `0 == " "` - the string is again transformed to a number. It follows similar conversion as before but blank spaces are trimmed. So, you end up comparing zero to a zero again.

Comment: @SMA However, when comparing `"" == " "` the base type is the same, so no conversion takes place. This time both are compared as they are and hence they are *not* equal. Moral of the story - just don't use `==`. The strict equality operator `===` will not perform type conversion so `"" === 0` is false because the two are different types. The strict equality operator would be transitive, but `==` is not *necessarily* transitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your values are numbers, you *can* do it by using flag properties on an object. First let's do it with discrete variables you have, then come back and look at doing it with a `wrong` array instead:

With discrete variables: *(edit: I really don't like this approach, strongly recommend skipping down to the next one instead)*

```js
var correct, wrong1, wrong2, wrong3, wrong4, flags, foundDuplicate, dbcount;

dbcount = 20;

//set correct, dbcount is at 20ish now, will end up in the thousands later
correct = Math.floor(Math.random()*dbcount);

do {
    wrong1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*dbcount);
    wrong2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*dbcount);
    wrong3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*dbcount);
    wrong4 = Math.floor(Math.random()*dbcount);
    flags = {};
    foundDuplicate = [correct, wrong1, wrong2, wrong3, wrong4].some(function(val) {
        // Have we seen this value before?
        if (flags[val]) {
            // Yes, we have a duplicate
            return true;
        }

        // No, remember that we've seen it and continue
        flags[val] = true;
        return false;
    });
}
while (foundDuplicate);
console.log("correct: " + correct);
console.log("wrong1:  " + wrong1);
console.log("wrong2:  " + wrong2);
console.log("wrong3:  " + wrong3);
console.log("wrong4:  " + wrong4);
```

This works because the numbers get converted to strings and used as property names. [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) returns `true` the first time a call to the iteration function returns a truthy value, `false` if no calls to the iteration function do.

With a `wrong` array instead, which has the advantage of not relying on converting the numbers to strings:

```js
var correct, wrong, newValue, duplicate, dbcount;

dbcount = 20;

//set correct, dbcount is at 20ish now, will end up in the thousands later
correct = Math.floor(Math.random()*dbcount);

wrong = [];
while (wrong.length < 4) {
    do {
        newValue = Math.floor(Math.random()*dbcount);
        duplicate = newValue === correct || wrong.some(function(val) {
            return val === newValue;
        });
    }
    while (duplicate);
    wrong.push(newValue);
}
console.log("correct: " + correct);
console.log("wrong:   " + wrong.join(", "));
```

The part that does the checks is in the `do..while` loop, so let's pick that apart a bit:

1. We start with a value in `correct` and an empty `wrong` array.
2. Our outer `while` loop loops until we have four entries in `wrong`.
3. Inside that, we enter the `do...while` loop.
4. We select a new value that we want to add to the `wrong` array.
5. Then we have this:

   ```
    duplicate = newValue === correct || wrong.some(function(val) {
        return val === newValue;
    });
   ```

   That sets the `duplicate` flag to `true` if our `newValue` is a duplicate of `correct` or any of the current values in `wrong`, `false` if it isn't, by doing this:

   - If `newValue === correct`, `duplicate` is set true and the `wrong.some` function is never called — we already know the value is a duplicate.
   - Otherwise, we call `wrong.some`, which will look through the entries in `wrong`, calling the callback (iterator) function we give it for each value. Our iterator function checks each value it's given (the existing values in the `wrong` array, one at a time) and checks whether they match `newValue`. If so, the iterator function returns `true` and that stops the `wrong.some` "loop," making `wrong.some` return `true` (`true` = yes, there is a duplicate value). If `wrong.some` reaches the end of the array and our iterator function never returns `true`, `wrong.some` returns `false` (`false` = there is no duplicate).
6. We keep looping inside the `do...while` until we find a value that isn't a duplicate.
7. Once we leave the `do...while`, we know `newValue` isn't a duplicate, so we add it to `wrong`.
8. Our outer `while` loop continues until `wrong` has four entries.

---

*(Note that `Array#some` is an ES5 feature not found on some quite old JavaScript engines. It can be shimmed/polyfilled.)*

Comment: opps refresh problems on my browser. sorry about that.

Comment: @thomas: `Array#some` is a handy utility function: It calls the function you give it (`function(val)` in the above) once for each value in the array, passing in the value as the first argument to that function, and stopping either when the function returns a truthy value (in which case it returns `true`) or when it runs out of entries in the array (in which case it returns `false`). So it's a handy way to test each value in an array to see if it matches some condition (in this case, whether it matches `correct` or any of our other wrong values).

Comment: @thomas: `flags` is only needed for the first snippet: We set a flag property on that object for each value we've already seen, so we know if it's a duplicate. I would use the second snippet rather than discrete variables.

Comment: you are awesome! thanks so much. The second snippet putting into an array definitely works for me. I'm still having a hard time imagining what is going on within the do { } section ,but I know it works and I can manipulate it enough to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: @thomas: No worries. I've added more explanation to the end of the answer.

Comment: not sure if you'd get this, if not that is ok. just wanted clarification with:    duplicate = newValue === correct || wrongStuff.some(function(val) { return val === newValue; }); .... I'm understanding that duplicate will = boolean. I'm not understanding how duplicate = true || false (true or false). I'm deducing that if both are false, it's false, if both are true it's true, and if one is false and one is true, then it's true, like how it may be handled in an if? didn't know a variable could hold info like this.

Comment: @thomas: The variable doesn't. Say we have `a = b || c`: The expression `b || c` is evaluated and the result is stored in `a`. (The *way* it's evaluated is that `b` is evaluated and, if "truthy," that's the result; if `b` is "falsey," then `c` is evaluated and it's the result.) That's exactly what we have here: `duplicate = newValue === correct || wrong.some(...)` The expression `newValue ===  correct || wrong.some(...)` is evaluated and the result of it is stored in `duplicate`. So `newValue === correct` is evaluated... *(cont'd)*

Comment: *(continuing)* ...and, if truthy, that's the result stored in `duplicate`; if not, `wrong.some(...)` is evaluated and that result is stored in `duplicate`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain that to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is like below

```
while(true){
    if(wrong1 === correct && wrong2 === correct && wrong3 === correct && wrong4 === correct &&
      wrong1 === wrong2 && wrong1 === wrong3 && wrong1 === wrong4 &&
      wrong2 === wrong3 && wrong2 === wrong4 &&
      wrong3 === wrong4){
           wrong1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*dbcount);
           wrong2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*dbcount);
           wrong3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*dbcount);
           wrong4 = Math.floor(Math.random()*dbcount);
    }
    else break;
}
```